# How do I set my palette to grayscale in c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, bitmap, palette

I'm reading live feed from a mono camera and need to take a snapshot when pressing a button.
So when I convert the pointer the camera passes me to a bitmap (8 bpp) for further image processing,
the colors get all weird like this

[image: weirdly colored image which should be grayscale]

I'm guessing it's because I didn't set the palette of the bitmap correctly, so I googled some and 
came across some code in VB, which sets the color palette of a bitmap to gray scale.
I want to do the same in C++ under Visual Studio 2010, only in C++ the constructor of color palette is sealed,thus I have no way of declaring a new grayscale palette and then assign it to my bitmap.

Below is the example code I found written in Visual Basics :

```
Dim bmpobj As Bitmap
Dim pal As System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette
pal = bmpobj.Palette
For i = 0 To 255
    pal.Entries(i) = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i)
Next
bmpobj.Palette = pal
```

So what I'm asking is this : Is there anyway to set my bitmap's palette to grayscale ?

Comment: Well I didn't find a solution to this, what I did was rewrite my project in C#. Took some time but worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think, just by changing the color palette, your image won't change to gray scale.

You will need to change each color pixel in the image to gray scale. The [algorithms are here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/).

Comment: Maybe I didn't provide enough info. I'm reading live feed from a mono camera and I need to save a .bmp when I click a snap button. But when I save the frame into a bitmap this happens. So I'm guessing I didn't set the palette correctly. That's why I'm asking help about palette, not because I want to convert my images grayscale.